# Recover Postgres Streaming Replication Slave from Archived Wal Logs

Tags: postgresql

I have set up a Postgres Hot Standby server by Streaming Replication. But My Standby server is asking for an old wal archive log which is currently not in Master's pg_xlog directory. But the file exists in the wal archive backup directory.

How can I configure Standby to read this file from backup directory? Or any way to manually copy this file to Standby Server ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the [`restore_command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY), in `recovery.conf`, to copy the requested file (%f) from the archive directory to the server's directory (%p).